# Two model-directions in one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have two models with each one class 
and in each class i create a list

```
public static List<category> category(int x)
```

and want to use them both in my webpage.

i have following code at the begining:

```
@model List<project3.Models.category>
@model List<project3.Models.Produkts>
@using project3.Models;
```

but i get an error that there is only one model-direction allowed per view.

i found the solution in the internet put the two classes in one model and to create a "main-class" in . kind of like this:

```
public class MainClass{
   public category category{get; set;}
   public Products Products{get; set;}
}
```

but then i'm not sure how i would integrate that in my view.

and i quite dont know how to transfer it on my "list"-model-direction. cause i just found examples where the model-direction kinda looked like this

```
@model project3.Models.category
```

i'm a total newbie, so sorry if its an idiotic question.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model *directive*, you mean.  Pay close attention to error messages, they're telling you what's wrong :)

In any event, if you have this model:

```
public class MainClass{
    public category category{get; set;}
    public Products Products{get; set;}
}
```

Then you would use it in your view by specifying that as your model directive:

```
@model project3.Models.MainClass
```

(Or whatever the correct namespace is for your `MainClass` model.)

There's nothing special about a "model" vs. any other class.  A class is a class, and you can specify any class (well, any type) that you want for the model directive in your view.  But, as the error tells you, you can only specify one.

As long as your controller sends an instance of that expected type to your view, then that's the "model" for the view.